# Search in all folders of imap mailbox with Mutt

Tags: mutt, email-client

I have just configured Mutt with my Gmail settings. I am able to fetch, read, and send email. I can also search messages in my inbox and specific folders. However, I would like to know if there is a way to search for messages in *all* folders at once. It seems a pretty basic feature and cannot find a way to do that with Mutt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use mutt-kz (which is a fork of mutt but which keeps up-to-date with it) and notmuch. You did not give any details such as *how* you fetch, read, and send email, so there is not much to go on. But a great combination for Gmail users is to use offlineimap + mutt-kz + notmuch.

Then, to search all folders, just do Esc+X, enter your search query, and press return. That's it.