# Searching over all IMAP folders on terminal?

Tags: 18.04, email, debian, imap, mutt

### Problem

I am aware that this problem might be rooted in the way IMAP works and what I can expect from a mail client. For IMAP *folders* are *mailboxes* and according to the protocol specification (afaik) an IMAP connection always connects to exactly one mailbox.

*alpine* and *mutt* seem to stick close to this principle, so <kbd>;</kbd> > <kbd>t</kbd> > <kbd>a</kbd> in alpine or <kbd>/</kbd> > `~B ...` in mutt only searches in the current folder (see also [1](https://superuser.com/questions/502528/advanced-imap-search-with-alpine), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91046/search-for-mail-content-with-mutt)).

There are similar issues in other recommended clients or indexers like *sup*, *notmuch*, etc. - either they do not offer this feature or they need additional software like *offlineimap* to mirror whole mailboxes to the local machine which I would like to avoid or have built-in from the start. (If all mails are local I can just `grep` so technically I do not need a mail client for this feature.) I am looking for a search experience close to what e.g. Thunderbird offers out of the box.

### Questions

1. **Is there an easy way (small macro or script) that allows server side (or locally cached) searching for strings over multiple folders in alpine or mutt?**
2. **Are there other terminal-only mail clients that have this rather basic feature built-in?**
3. **If the answer to 1. and 2. is *No* what would be the easiest way to get this feature on the command line?**

#### Setup

- dovecot IMAP server
- Debian/Ubuntu client
- e.g. SSH connection to client
- folders on the server are next to each other, not nested under INBOX or similar

#### What I have tried

- <kbd>;</kbd> > <kbd>t</kbd> > <kbd>a</kbd> in alpine mail folder list fails with `[Scan not valid on this IMAP server]` (same as [here](https://alpine-alpha.u.washington.narkive.com/tFWi20Ze/fulltext-search-within-messages#post4))
- scripting this via python or similar by adapting snippets like [this one](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/python-manipulating-imap-mailbox-michael-bear) should be possible, but this seems like such a basic feature that I want to know if there are canonical solutions available
- using *offlineimap* kind of works but (unnecessarily?) requires quite some space locally
- it has been recommended [elsewhere on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697887/search-in-all-folders-of-imap-mailbox-with-mutt) to use *mutt-kz* (probably *neomutt* now?) and install *notmuch* as well as *offlineimap*. This is suboptimal (see above).